# How can I upgrade eclipse helios?

Tags: eclipse, upgrade, helios

I tried to upgrade eclipse helios by `Help--> Check for updates`. But the progressing bar stops at 38% and never completes. `I'm developing php applications using this eclipse helios.` Can anyone suggest how can I upgrade this eclipse helios ?

```
I'm using windows 7 (64-bit) and my current eclipse version is 3.6.0
```

Thank you

Comment: Do you want to update some components in Eclipse or do you want to update to a whole new Eclipse version like Kepler?

Comment: Thank you for the response. Can I use `eclipse Kepler` for php codings?

Comment: I've never used Eclipse or PHP before but I think it's just plug ins. You should know best which plugins they are and can check if they are available for Kepler.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Helped a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also face a similar issue sometimes with eclipse updates. If you want to complete upgrade to the Kepler version, I would strongly advise you to download a fresh copy of it from the official web-site. And yes you can use it for PHP coding as well, its just a matter of setting up proper plugins. The PDT (PHP Development Tools) plugin is available for Kepler.

Following are the links

1.[Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/)

2.[PDT plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/downloads/)

Comment: That's what I thought. +1

Comment: Wow thanks a lot. This worked perfectly. I downloaded eclipse Kepler and installed PDT. Now it's working without any issues. +1